# Validate Username, email while user is typing

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin

I want to validate the username and email while the user is typing it in the entry control.
Using behaviors seems to be the ultimate way.
Please guide me as to exactly how to implement it.

I have azure function to validate whether the email is already exists or not.

I expect the output to be while the user is typing the username show green tick if his username is valid and not taken by any other.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to let the user type, then do the checking 2-3 seconds after he finished typing?

Comment: @Bogdan Doicin I am ok with it.
I need as to how to implement it.

Comment: You sure you want to create an attack vector for a username enumeration attack on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, i would have to assume you are using some kind of textbox for the user input (Probably an entry). There is an event called TextChanged, you can do whatever you want with the user input over there, it will change for every keystroke and you will have 2 things to look up for, the old text value and the new text value.

In spite of that I would strongly recommend you to use the Completed event, since it will raise once the user finished the input and press the return keystroke, and then you can simply send the text over to your azure validation method.

Comment: how about Unfocused implementation?
I get what you are asking me to do my point is exactly how it is to be done?
I have already implemented textchanged event.

Comment: You can use the unfocused event too. What you mean by how is it done? show the code you have and i ll help you accordingly from what you gave us there is no way for me to help you further

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `TextBox` for the user inputs, you can use the `TextChanged` event to validate. This will be be able to validate while the user is typing. I recommend using a try catch block as well to avoid any NullReference exceptions crashing your program.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AzureValidateFunction(TextBoxName.Text);
}
```

This code is for WPF so your syntax might be a little different, hope that helps!

Comment: Problem with your function is that TextChanged means every stroke so you would be sending every time you get a new char to the azure function which validates if its good or not, i dont think this is a very good approach to be frank

Comment: @nalnpir maybe you could add conditions to the `TextChange` event, such as "input length", or invoke validation when the end matches some characters like ".com"